# Looping back to the beginning of a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, control-flow

I am building a simple rock paper scissors game. Everytime you win, you gain a point. Same for the computer. Between the player and computer, the first to get 3 points wins. Everything worked fine but I wanted to add an extra feature which is an option to play again.

```
import random

user_name_input = input("What is your name?: ")
print(f"Oh hello {user_name_input}!")

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]



while True:
    user_points = 0
    comp_points = 0
    print("ROCK--PAPER--SCISSORS!")
    user_choice = input("SHOOT!: ").lower()
    comp_choice = random.choice(options)

    if user_choice not in options:
        print("Please choose either rock, paper or scissors")
        print("\n")
        continue

    # CONDITIONS
    if user_choice == "rock" and comp_choice == "scissors":
        print("WIN")
        print(f"Computer's Choice: {comp_choice}")
        user_points += 1
        print(f"Your Points: {user_points}")
        print(f"Computer's Points: {comp_points}")

        print("\n")

    elif user_choice == "paper" and comp_choice == "rock":
        print("WIN")
        print(f"Computer's Choice: {comp_choice}")
        user_points += 1
        print(f"Your Points: {user_points}")
        print(f"Computer's Points: {comp_points}")

        print("\n")
    elif user_choice == "scissors" and comp_choice == "paper":
        print("WIN")
        print(f"Computer's Choice: {comp_choice}")
        user_points += 1
        print(f"Your Points: {user_points}")
        print(f"Computer's Points: {comp_points}")

        print("\n")

    elif user_choice == comp_choice:
        print(f"Computer's Choice: {comp_choice}")
        print("Same picks, play again")
        print(f"Your Points: {user_points}")
        print(f"Computer's Points: {comp_points}")
        print("\n")
    else:
        print("LOSS")
        print(f"Computer's Choice: {comp_choice}")
        comp_points += 1
        print(f"Your Points: {user_points}")
        print(f"Computer's Points: {comp_points}")
        print("\n")

    if user_points == 3:
        print("You've won")
        print(
            f"You did it {user_name_input}!, you're a rock, paper, scissors MASTER!!!!")
            quit()


    elif comp_points == 3:
        print("You've lost")
        print(f"Sorry {user_name_input}, you'll get it next time!")
        quit()
```

I added this condition at the bottom, and I expected that the using the "continue" statement, python would loop back to the beginning of the while loop, and the game would run again. However this messed up my program entirely and now when I run it, after just one play, the computer asks the user if they want to play again. It's not looping 3 times like the original.

```
    if play_again == "yes":
        user_points = 0
        comp_points = 0
        print("Great! Let's go!")
        continue
    else:
        play_again == "no"
        print("Ok thanks for playing")
        quit()
```

Does anyone know why? Thank you.

Comment: You have to reset `user_points` and `comp_points` back to zero. loops don't reset values that are declared outside the loop.

Comment: okay... thanks for your answer but can you elaborate a little bit

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You have to reset user_points and comp_points back to zero. loops don't reset values that are declared outside the loop.

If play_again == "yes", then the compiler re executes from the top. But in your loop, you only reset `user_choice` and `comp_choice` to a new value, so `user_points` and `comp_points` stays the same.

Lets assume in the last game the user won, which means `user_points` is 3. Now if the player continues to play, `user_points` still has the value of 3. Now it will still let you play one round since you didn't check the points at the start. Now when you finish the first round and you check the points, `user_points` is still 3, so the loop will end.

To fix this you need to change:

```
    if play_again == "yes":
        print("Great! Let's go!")

        continue
    else:
        play_again == "no"
        print("Ok thanks for playing")
        quit()
```

to

```
    if play_again == "yes":
        print("Great! Let's go!")
        user_points = 0
        comp_points = 0
        continue
    else:
        play_again == "no"
        print("Ok thanks for playing")
        quit()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer... however, the problem still persisted after I implemented your changes. After just 1 play, the program will ask the user if they want to play again, instead of letting them play 3 times.

Comment: How did you implement it, post you new implementation's code

Comment: I just added it under everything else. Specifically under the last if...elif statement for if the user wants to play again.

Comment: I don't see it, where did you add it?

Comment: alright its edited now, sorry about that i misunderstood your question. –

Answer (score 0):

You can add all in an function
import random

```
def game():
    user_name_input = input("What is your name?: ")
    print(f"Oh hello {user_name_input}!")

    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

    user_points = 0
    comp_points = 0
    
    while True:
        # All your while loop

    play_again = input("Do you want to play again?: ")

    if play_again == "yes":
        print("Great! Let's go!")
        game()  # This calls again your function
        
    elif play_again == "no":
        print("Ok thanks for playing")

game()
```

Comment: Dont do this! if you play enough times it will eventually develop into a stackoverflow!

Comment: Not really, as no new variables are created there is no memory increment

Comment: Yes it does, to know why you will need to get a bunch of low level language knowledge, every time you call a function, you use the `call` function, which pushes your current address onto the stack, so you use up some memory. Of course python don't do it like this, but this example is the easiest to explain. If you loop too many times in python, you will get a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` which is kinda a python version of stackoverflow

Comment: I literally just ran the code 100 times and it was always taking up about 11mb of ram, I don't have much knowledge but I'm sure no one will ever play this more than 100 times in a row

Comment: Remember, this is not for just this code. We are teaching someone, so we have to give him good coding practice. He might miss use your method elsewhere and cause the exception.

Comment: Also if this was C, 100 * 64 (`sizeof(uintptr_t)`) + 100 * 3 * 64 (the 3 values u r declaring in the loop) = 25600, so it only took up 25kb of space. This is not quite dangerous in code with human input, but it is in code that is all automatic. A computer will go through this loops millions of times if there is no human delay